Data source repair not working
Out of the blue, two table in my PostGIS are being flagged for multiple users as needing the data source repaired.
The permissions, schema and database have not changed. Navigating to the table in the 'repair data source' dialogue does not work, and the error persists. The table load fine in FME and ArcGIS, which leads me to believe this is a QGIS problem.
I have the same problem whether I look at the table as an admin or a user. In pgAdmin, I can see the table is where it should be with no problems, or changes.
